# Problem in understanding a concept regarding path connectedness.

Tags: general-topology

How can I visualize the fact that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus A$ is path connected where $A$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be points of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$. Find an arc of a circle going from $p$ to $q$. There are uncountable many choices for such arcs and two distinct arcs have no points in common other than $p$ and $q$. But $A$ only has a countable number of elements. Therefore, there will be some arc that contains no point of $A$, thus providing a path from $p$ to $q$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$.